# How do I pull down all rows for a table with the list name that was selected previously in mySQL and Android PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have a shopping list app for android, I am designing it using PHP and i have a database on mySQL. In that database i have a table called Products. In products there is just two columns, list and product. Each list will have a number of products. I want to be able to populate a page with all of the products in whatever list the user of the app has selected.

I am using PHP with JSON to read the information from mySQL. Here is similar to what i want but this will read all lists and products from the database. i just want the list that the user has selected on the screen.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["list"] = $row["list"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];


        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the android app would need to to a HTTP request to get the data, pass along a GET variable with the value of the table the user selected in the application. Then read the value in PHP with `$_GET["table"]`.